# Initialize redux form with FieldArray fields

Tags: forms, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I have a redux form with form fields as **FieldArray**. 
Initialising redux-form from state is pretty [straightforward](https://redux-form.com/6.4.3/examples/initializeFromState) but my form has list of fields ([FieldArray](http://redux-form.com/6.4.3/examples/fieldArrays/)) and there is no documentation for initialising FieldArray form.

The problem seems to be because of field names (eg: `members[0].lastName, members[0].firstName` etc)
 And I've tried manually passing these keys but still got no form initialisation, please help.

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround, we can add `enableReinitialize: true` in form configuration object or we can use `componentdidmout` and calling arrayInsert action and passing all the parameters. Used this github issue:
https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/2349

Answer (score 0):

The name of FieldArray should have same name as the name of data you are going to pass in initialvalues of redux form.

fields props of Field Array component has data present only if we have pass valid name of Field Array